# lyluatex on Windows -- "The score doesn't contain any music"...but it does

Tags: luatex, windows

I'm trying to use the `lyluatex` package. I made a document that contains only one of the examples from the *Latex For Musicians* guide, with a few additional package options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[program={"C:/Program Files (x86)/LilyPond/usr/bin/lilypond.exe"},debug=true,nofragment]{lyluatex}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    This is a LilyPond snippet \lilypond{c'e'g'} embedded in the textusing the \verb|\lilypond| command.
    This is another LilyPond excerpt that uses the \texttt{lilypond} environment:
    \medskip
    \begin{lilypond}
        \score{
            \relative c' {
                \time 4/4
                \clef treble
                c4 d8 e f8 g a b | c4 b8 a g8 f e d |
                c8 g'e g c,8 g'e g | c,4 e c r \bar "|."
            }
        } % end of score
    \end{lilypond}
    \medskip 
    End of document.
\end{document}
```

The output is (unfortunately) as follows:

```
Process started: lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape "lylyuatex-testdoc"

lualatex: warning: running with administrator privileges

This is LuaTeX, Version 1.11.2 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) 
 system commands enabled.
(

./lylyuatex-testdoc.tex

LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 3.397 seconds

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/article.cls"

Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/size10.clo"

)

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/lyluatex/lyluatex.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lua

texbase/luatexbase.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty"))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex"

)

)

))

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty"

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg"

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def"

)

)

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/minibox/minibox.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3deprecation.def"

)

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def"

)

)

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty"

)

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/currfile/currfile.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty"

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty"

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty"

)

))

)

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty"

)

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty"

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty"

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-

pic.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty"

)

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg"

)

)

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppluatex.def"

)

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty"

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty"

)

)

)

(./lylyuatex-testdoc.aux

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty"

))

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty"

)

)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdie

k/pdflscape.sty"

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/gr

aphics/lscape.sty")

)

(lyluatex)  Compiling score tmp-ly/ec8310ab69e70dc3e0d5447553471176 with LilyPond executable '"C:/Program Files (x86)/LilyPond/usr/bin/lilypond.exe"'.

(lyluatex)  GNU LilyPond 2.18.2

(lyluatex)  Command:
"""C:/Program Files (x86)/LilyPond/usr/bin/lilypond.exe"" -dno-point-and-click -djob-count=2 -dno-delete-intermediate-files -I "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Code\TeX\LaTeX\thesisbook/" -I "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Code\TeX\LaTeX\thesisbook/" -o "tmp-ly/ec8310ab69e70dc3e0d5447553471176" tmp-ly/ec8310ab69e70dc3e0d5447553471176.ly 2>&1"

Module lyluatex Warning: The score doesn't contain any music:
(lyluatex)               this will probably cause bad output. on input line 18

C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109: 
Module lyluatex Error: 
(lyluatex)             LilyPond failed to compile the score.
(lyluatex)             Please check the log file
(lyluatex)             and the generated LilyPond code in
(lyluatex)             tmp-ly/ec8310ab69e70dc3e0d5447553471176.log
(lyluatex)             tmp-ly/ec8310ab69e70dc3e0d5447553471176.ly
(lyluatex)             
(lyluatex)             on input line 18

stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109: in function <C:/P
rogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:108>
    (...tail calls...)
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:555: in method 'chec
k_compilation'
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1180: in method 'wri
te_latex'
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1109: in method 'pro
cess'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\ly@compilescore ...directlua {ly.score:process()}

l.18    \end{lilypond}

[1

{C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map

}

]

(./lylyuatex-testdoc.aux)

)
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 415 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 5 attribute, 49 glue_spec
, 5 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:60,3:12,4:6,5:32,6:5,7:168,9:35,10:1,11:10

<c:/program files/miktex 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmmono10-regular.otf

>

<c:/
program files/miktex 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf

>

Output written on lylyuatex-testdoc.pdf (1 page, 8257 bytes).

SyncTeX written on lylyuatex-testdoc.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on lylyuatex-testdoc.log.

Process exited with error(s)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong. The compile command is being run through TeXstudio rather than via commandline but I don't think that's the issue. I'm trying to use this package for the typesetting of inline examples in a thesis and I'd really like to figure this out!

Comment: It works with texlive but fails with miktex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is it relatively easy to switch from MikTeX to TeXlive? Or could I just manually install the package? What is it exactly about the MikTeX version that doesn't work?

Comment: You can simply install texlive beside your miktex. Switching between miktex and texlive can then be done by changing your PATH environment variable. I don't know why it doesn't work with miktex, I don't have the time to debug now. Ask the lyluatex maintainer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the advice, I'm installing TeXlive now