# How to use lyLuaTeX?

Tags: luatex, music, lilypond

I am trying to use lyLuaTeX but it is not working. I've read the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/lyluatex/lyluatex.pdf) but I don't understand how to get it to work.

I am on Windows 10, using [TeX Live (first comment)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519161/lyluatex-on-windows-the-score-doesnt-contain-any-music-but-it-does). Here is what I am trying to compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[program=C:/Program Files (x86)/LilyPond/usr/bin/lilypond.exe]{lyluatex}

\begin{document}

Help.

\lilypond{ c' d' e'}

\end{document}
```

I've added `--shell-escape` to the LuaLaTeX preferences on TeXworks [above the file name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82699/how-to-enable-shell-escape-in-texworks), and then I press compile with LuaLaTeX. However, I receive the following error.

```
Module lyluatex Error: LilyPond could not be started.
(lyluatex)             Please check that LuaLaTeX is started with the
(lyluatex)             --shell-escape option, and that 'program'
(lyluatex)             points to a valid LilyPond executable.
(lyluatex)             on input line 8

stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...iles/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109: in function <
...iles/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:108>
    (...tail calls...)
    ...es/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/scripts/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1081: in method 'p
rocess'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\ly@compilescore ...directlua {ly.score:process()}

l.8 \lilypond{ c' d' e'}

?
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: have you installed lilypond? (it is not part of normal tex distributions)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I have.

Comment: you perhaps need to quote the path to lilypond.exe, but easier it is to simply add lilypond.exe to your windows path variable. Then you don't need the program option.

Comment: [This answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676807/150166) directly replies to this one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on WIndows 10 and LilyPond 2.22.2. I fixed it by moving LilyPond to a path with no spaces.

This MWE works for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[program=/bin/lilypond/usr/bin/lilypond.exe]{lyluatex}
\begin{document}

\lilypondfile[staffsize=17]{/score.ly}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is unanswered and someone might stumble upon this, I answered a very similar question in [music.sx](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/76950/lilypond-with-latex/78080#78080). The best strategy to integrate music into LaTeX is by making the music snippets and text document separately, then integrate the snippets as pdfs with graphicx.